# Divisibility of a large number

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Let $N$ be a large number of 258 digits consisting all 1's except two digits at 145th and 146th digits. If $N$ is divisible by 17 then what is the two missing numbers?

Comment: What have you tried?  Might be a good idea to start with the number which consists of $258$ $1's$.  What is that number $\pmod {17}$?

Comment: Have you tried to reduce the number modulo $17$?  Asking about a problem with little indication of your interest in solving it (*context*) will leave Readers guessing what kind of response is sought.

Comment: 145th from which end ?

Comment: I knew the answer . But for some problem in my phone I couldn't write the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose, from right, 146th digit is $a$ and 145th digit is $b$, we have:

$N=1+10+100+ . . . + 10^{143}+b\times 10^{144}+a\times 10^{145}+10^{146}+10^{147} + . . . + 10^{257}$

$1+10+100+ . . . + 10^{143}=\frac {10^{144}-1}{10-1}$

$10^{146}+10^{147} + . . . + 10^{257}=10^{146}\times \frac{10^{112}-1}{10-1}$

$N=\frac {1}{9}[(10^{144}-1+10^{146}(10^{112}-1)+9\times 10^{144}(b+10a)$

$10^{144}-1≡10^{(17-1)^9}-1≡ 0 \mod 17$

$10^{112}-1=10^{(17-1)^7}-1≡0 \mod 17$

Therefore we must have:

$9b+90a=17 k$

$a$ and $b$ must be less than 9 and possible solutions are:

$(a, b)=(1,7), (3, 4), (5, 1), (6, 8), (8, 5)$

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**:

$\newcommand{\s}{1111111111111111\\}\newcommand{\t}{11111111111111mn\\}\hspace{129px}11\\\s\s\s\s\s\s\t\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\s\underline{\s}$

Answer (score 1):

By Fermat's little theorem you have that $17$ divides $10^{16}-1=9999999999999999$. Dividing by $9$, you get $17$ divides $111111111111111111$ ($16$ digits). Then, you can drop 16 consecutive $1's$ of your number  $N$ and your number should remain being a multiple of $17$. If you drop the 16*9=144 $1$'s from the left and the 16*7=112 $1's$ from the right of the number $N$. You get that $\overline{mn}$ has to be a multiple of $17$.  So the options are $\overline{mn}=17,34,51,68,85$

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

Divide $1$ by $17$ until you get a periodic number. Multiply the period by $17$.

Comment: This is too obscure for me.  The problem asks to determine a value (different than one) for two specific digits.  I suppose that the consecutiveness of those digits allows us to reduce the solution to computation of one number, but even so your hint has no apparent connection to the location of those digits.

Comment: I think the hint is that you may want to find a number of the form $111...11$ which is multiple of $17$. And the way he's suggesting to obtain this is that if $1/17=0.(abcd...m)$ where $p=(abcd...m)$ is the period, then $1/17=p/9999...9$. Which means that $17$ divides 999..9, and therefore $17$ divides $111..111$.